# Memory not released when popViewController Called

Tags: ios, memory

Below is the code in which i have some doubts:-

```
MyController *vc= [MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myController"
                                                    bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Then, i pop my controller  by pressing the back button on nav bar.

The problem is memory is increased by 5mb(On Activity Monitor) for the first time.And when i pop the controller it doesnt get released.
And when i do the push and pop again and again the memory increases by small amount and decreased too.

UIView *myView=[UIView alloc]init];

self.vi=myView;

[myView release];

UIScrollView *mySv=[UIScrollView alloc]init];

self.sv=mySv;

[mySvrelease];

UIProgressView*myPv=[UIProgressViewalloc]init];

self.pv=myPv;

[myPvrelease];

UIWebView *myWv=[UIWebView alloc]init];

self.wv=myWv;

[myWv release];

-(void)dealloc
{
  [wv relase];

[sv release]

[pv release];

[vi release];

[super dealloc];

}

wv,sv,pv,vi are MyViewControoler variables which have retain attribute.
I wrote this code to check the memory management concepts,but iam confused now seeing the activity monitor and instruments results.

I have verified that no object is getting leaked in my MyController class by using Instruments on it.

Answer (score 1):

MyViewController have a content which does a leaks

Comment: which type of contents you are reffering to?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a memory leak. iOS cache the controllers you have visited recently. It will get deallocated by iOS itself when your application needs memory to execute some other tasks.

Comment: Yes, it is a leak. No, iOS does not cache recently used controllers.

Comment: If its a leak, it should increase memory usage each time.

Comment: Actually iam also confused in this if its a leak or not.Please help

Comment: Does anyone have apple doc which states that apple cache the controllers in my case the navigation stack

Answer (score -1):

try this method in MyViewController.m file

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    //release any object thats retained into the memory
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I have released all my class variables in dealloc method.